# How to place the python packages to be install (using apt-get) in requirements.txt in GCP app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, poppler

I am trying to run my app in GCP App engine. My Requirements.txt file looks like below:

```
pillow==5.1.0
pybase64==0.4.0
poppler-utils==0.68.0
```

Poppler-utils can be installed only using sudo apt-get in GCP command line tool. How can I give it in requirements.txt so that the app installs that package alone using sudo apt-get command ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The requirements.txt file is specific to pip and can only include Python packages.

If you need to install an OS-level package (with apt-get), you'll need to use the Docker based App Engine Flexible environment (Standard doesn't provide this functionality) and create a [custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/about-custom-runtimes).

You can find a Dockerfile example [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-runtime#kubernetes-engine--other-docker-hosts) extending the default python image:

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python
```

You'll then need to add the `poppler-utils` package via:

```
RUN apt-get install poppler-utils
```

You'll find more information about building custom runtimes for App Engine Flexible [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build).