# How to install poppler on gcp app engine using dockerfile?

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, poppler

I'm deploying an app which is using pdf2image to gcp app engine. When I wanted to test it I got an error:

> pdf2image.exceptions.PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52403499/how-to-place-the-python-packages-to-be-install-using-apt-get-in-requirements-t/52407341) and added dockerfile to my project, this is how it looks:

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python

# Create a virtualenv for dependencies. This isolates these packages from
# system-level packages.
# Use -p python3 or -p python3.7 to select python version. Default is version 2.
RUN apt-get install poppler-utils
RUN virtualenv -p python3.7 /env

# Setting these environment variables are the same as running
# source /env/bin/activate.
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH

# Copy the application's requirements.txt and run pip to install all
# dependencies into the virtualenv.
ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

# Add the application source code.
ADD . /app

# Run a WSGI server to serve the application. gunicorn must be declared as
# a dependency in requirements.txt.
CMD gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

I also changed the app.yaml file:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
```

And now when I try to deploy the app I get:

> Step 2/9 : RUN apt-get install poppler-utils
>
> ---> Running in db1e5bebd0a8
>
> Reading package lists...
>
> Building dependency tree...
>
> Reading state information...
>
> E: Unable to locate package poppler-utils
>
> The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install poppler-utils' returned a non-zero 
>   code: 100
>
> ERROR
>
> ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: exit status 100

I also tried python-poppler instead of poppler-utils and got the same error.

I found this [post about installing poppler](https://gist.github.com/Dayjo/618794d4ff37bb82ddfb02c63b450a81) and now I'm wondering if I can do this in dockerfile, I haven't work with docker before, this was my first dockerfile.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should fetch the package with `apt-get update` before installing it, otherwise the package manager won't find it and throw this error.

As well, installing the package will require you to confirm the installation by typing `Y/n` in a prompt, which you won't be able to do in a Dockerfile. To avoid this, add the flag `-y` to the `apt-get install` command.

Adding this changes to your Dockerfile would look like this:

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install poppler-utils -y
RUN virtualenv -p python3.7 /env

# Rest of your build steps...
```